# Boot time: prefetching files article

Tags: boot, startup

I am doing research and I am looking for an article that I read a long time ago, cannot remember where it was. Perhaps someone will know it and can provide a citation.

Article described an experimental method of speeding up boot time that worked like this: they made a list of files which were read on bootup, grouped them on disk, and I think also tweaked the filesystem so it read all of them at once at the start. Not sure about that last part.

Seems *ureadahead* and *e4rat* are doing essentially what I am researching.

Comment: Isn't that what `preload` does? Or did `preload` just cache often used applications after boot...

Comment: I was thinking of [ureadahead](https://launchpad.net/ureadahead).

Comment: @ByteCommander Wikipedia describes preload as a tool that works in spare time, although a dead reference below mentions improving boot time. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it. First post describes how ureadahead works. Will keep searching.

1. https://lwn.net/Articles/401561/
2. https://lwn.net/Articles/299483/